# Looping through array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have an array of objects, with each object looking like this:

```
var car = {
    make: "", 
    model: "", 
    price: ""
}
```

I'm trying to loop through each object while looking to see if a specific property is defined like so:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    if (obj[i].price == ""){
        // empty
    }
}
```

For some reason I keep getting the value as undefined. Is there a different/correct way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: What value is undefined?

Comment: How big is the array? `i <= 5` is for an array with at least 6 elements. You should use `i < obj.length`.

Comment: if i were to just console.log(obj[0].price), or any index in my given range, I get undefined.

Comment: Can't you create a snippet to us?

Comment: give us whole array

Comment: @Barmar I used 5 as an example - i have length checking happening already. I just stripped that out to keep it simple.

Comment: The objects obviously aren't what you think, because the code is fine.

Comment: First of all u can do that: for (i = 0; i <= myArr.length; i++), without checking the lenght elsewhere and so u can change later the array size without changing the code. Also, what is the Index of those Objects?

Comment: @Barmar If I don't specify the property of the object, and just output obj[1], it gives me that object fine. As soon as I add obj[1].price to the mix, I get undefined.

Comment: @Jojo, without equal `i < myArr.length`

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof obj[1])` say?

Comment: How about the for... in syntax? https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: @ Nina. of course! Thanks. Actually getting tired... coding since 10 hours.

Comment: Best with the [`for of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) syntax for this job... but you have to have an array of objects first.. which i suspect.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to loop through each object ... to see if a specific property is defined

Here is an example of looping through an array of objects and printing whether or not a property is defined for each object. Just be careful with those truthiness checks, which are not the same thing as being "defined". You probably want to look at [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

```
const cars = [
    { make : 'Toyota', model : 'Prius', price : 15000 },
    { make : 'Honda', model : 'Civic', price : 10000 },
    { make : 'Ford', model : 'Edsel', price : 0 }
];

cars.forEach((car) => {
    console.log(`${car.make} ${car.model}:`);
    if (car.hasOwnProperty('price')) {
        console.log('Has a price.');
    }
    if (car.price) {
        console.log('Costs some money.');
    }
});
```

This will print:

```
Toyota Prius:
Has a price.
Costs some money.
Honda Civic:
Has a price.
Costs some money.
Ford Edsel:
Has a price.
```

The [Ford Edsel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsel) has a price, but shouldn't cost any money.